# Jetty 8 web sockets

Tags: jetty, websocket

I've downloaded the latest Jetty 8 Hightide, but cannot get WebSockets to work. I unzip the distribution, put my .war file in the webapps folder and start:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketServlet
```

I've verified that the JETTY_HOME/lib folder contains the jetty-websocket.jar and it contains the WebSocketServlet class file.

I've had this running before with the milestone releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, it appears that web sockets are no longer available by default, so the following code is needed in the context XML file:

```
<Set name="extraClasspath"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/lib/jetty-websocket-<version>.jar</Set>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly this was changed since the milestone release, but it's the normal jetty behaviour. Jetty tries to hide its own implementation classes from the applications that it deploys (e.g. so you don't accidently get the Jetty version of SLF4J, and so that applications don't mess with the Jetty internals unless the deployer has explictly allowed it). It looks like the websocket servlet has fallen in line with that behaviour.

Comment: Based on this, it shouldn't be the case:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/Jetty_Classloading#Setting_System_Classes
But maybe that refers to 7 and it's been changed for 8?

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same using jetty-maven-plugin and version `8.0.3.v20111011`. However the solution was simple. Just include the `jetty-websocket` as a compiled scope dependency (i.e. don't declared scope).

Relevant sections of `pom.xml`:

```
...
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jetty.version>8.0.3.v20111011</jetty.version>
</properties>
...

<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use Maven.

Comment: I could not get this to work.Is there something specific other than this that I need to do?

Comment: Neeraj, please use exactly this version: 8.0.3.v20111011.

Other versions, like 8.1.10.v20130312 do not work this way.

Martin, you could move the dependencies to the plugin dependencies: <plugin><groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>..<dependencies<dependency>..DEPENDENCY HERE ... </plugin>

Answer (score 1):

```
copy %JETTY_ROOT%\lib\jetty-websocket-<version>.jar %SERVLET_ROOT%\WEB-INF\lib
```

Seemed to work great for me!

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem running Jetty from Eclipse via WST plugin. Here is how I solved it. Under workspace's .metadata directory found application's context:
[workspace's .metadata]/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/[configuration id like 'tmp1']/contexts/[app name].xml .
Edited it to include the following under Configure tag: `<Set name="extraClasspath">[jetty install dir]/lib/jetty-websocket-8.1.2.v20120308.jar;[jetty install dir]/lib/jetty-util-8.1.2.v20120308.jar</Set>`

Had to hardcode the Jetty install dir, since my Jetty is installed outside of Eclipse and doing the `<SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>` resolves to the jetty home under .metadata.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of the already correct answer, no?

Comment: It depends on who is asking. If it's someone who tried, but can't make it work following the first answer, then no, it's not a duplicate. But if it's the author of the first answer then - yes.