# Jetty 9 websocket with CometD

Tags: websocket, jetty, cometd, jetty-9

I am seeing a error while deploying CometD server with Jetty.

```
[20140514 15:31:55:725 IST (main) org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle#setFailed 209 WARN] - FAILED org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl@751
5ff74: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing ServletContext
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing ServletContext
        at org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport.init(WebSocketTransport.java:61)
        at org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl.initializeServerTransports(BayeuxServerImpl.java:231)
```

I am not sure now how and which jar needs to be added.

I have gone through [Jetty 8 web sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758322/jetty-8-web-sockets/7771173#7771173) but still not able to run since there is no jetty-websocket.version.jar in jetty-9-distribution, instead there is new websocket folder which has lots of websocket jars.

Comment: Did you figure out how to use WebSocket with Jetty9 ?